# How to use Touch Bar via WebKit (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, safari, webkit

Where do I find a documentation about how to use the Touch Bar in Java Script ?

Tynymce is already using Touch Bar:
https://www.tinymce.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That rich text editing interface appears whenever you set `contenteditable="true"` on an HTML element.

There is no documentation for accessing the Touch Bar in JavaScript yet.